# Failure To Get Specific Text From Regex Group

Tags: c#, regex

My example is working fine with greedy when I use to capture the whole value of a string and a group(in group[1] ONLY) enclose with **a pair of single quote**.

But when I want to capture the whole value of a string and a group(in group[1] ONLY) enclose with **multiple pair of single quote** , it only capture the value of string enclose with **last pair** but not the string between first and last single quotes.

```
            string val1 = "Content:abc'23'asad";          
            string val2 = "Content:'Scale['#13212']'ta";

            Match match1 = Regex.Match(val1, @".*'(.*)'.*");
            Match match2 = Regex.Match(val2, @".*'(.*)'.*");
            if (match1.Success)
            {
                string value1 = match1.Value;
                string GroupValue1 = match1.Groups[1].Value;
                Console.WriteLine(value1);
                Console.WriteLine(GroupValue1);

                string value2 = match2.Value;
                string GroupValue2 = match2.Groups[1].Value;
                Console.WriteLine(value2);
                Console.WriteLine(GroupValue2);

                Console.ReadLine();

                // using greedy For val1 i am getting perfect value for-
                // value1--->Content:abc'23'asad
                // GroupValue1--->23

                // BUT using greedy For val2 i am getting the string elcosed by last single quote-
                // value2--->Content:'Scale['#13212']'ta
                // GroupValue2---> ]
                // But i want GroupValue2--->Scale['#13212']
            }
```

Comment: While it's technically possible to have this sort of nested thing in Regex, it sounds like what you actually need is a parser.

Comment: If you need to solve it with a regex, or with any parser, you need to define where the `'` are to be considered delimiters and where a part of the substring matched. Otherwise, there is no solution. Why do you know `Scale['#13212']` should be in Group 1? Also, try `[^']*'((?:'[^']*'|[^'])*)'.*`

Comment: that's just too greedy .. [`'(.*)'`](https://regex101.com/r/ZkuERX/1)

Comment: You can get anything you want using dot-net regex. Unfortunately, you're not clear exactly what you want, and / or do not show exactly the results input and output. It would be a waste of time to give a speculative solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your existing regex is that you are using too many greedy modifiers. That first one is going to grab everything it can until it runs into the second to last apostrophe in the string. That's why your end result of the second example is just the stuff within the last pair of quotes.

There are a few ways to approach this. The simplest way is to use Slai's suggestion - just a pattern to grab anything and everything within the most "apart" apostrophes available:

```
'(.*)'
```

A more explicitly defined approach would be to slightly tweak the pattern you are currently using. Just change the first greedy modifier into a lazy one:

```
.*?'(.*)'.*
```

Alternatively, you could change the dot in that first and last section to instead match every character *other than* an apostrophe:

```
[^']*'(.*)'[^']*
```

Which one you end up using depends on what you're personally going after. One thing of note, though, is that according to Regex101, the first option involves the fewest steps, so it will be the most efficient method. However, it also dumps the rest of the string, but I don't know if that matters to you.

Answer (score 0):

First off use named match capture groups such as `(?<Data> ... )` then you can access that group by its name in C# such as `match1.Groups["Data"].Value`.

---

Secondly try not to use `*` which means zero to many. Is there really going to be **no** data? For a majority of the cases, that answer is no, there is data.

Use the `+`, one to many instead.

IMHO `*` screws up more patterns because it has to find zero data, when it does that, it skips ungodly amounts of data. When you know there is data use `+`.

---

It is better to match on what is known, than unknown and we will create a pattern to what is **known**. Also in that light use the negation set `[^ ]` to capture text such as `[^']+` which says capture everything that is **not** a `'`, one to many times.

**Pattern**

```
 Content:\x27?[^\x27?]+\x27(?<Data>[^\27]+?)\x27
```

The results on your two sets of data are `23` and `#13212` and placed into match capture `group[1]` **and** `group["Data"]`.

Note `\x27` is the hex escape of the single quote `'`. `\x22` is for the double quote `"`, which I bet is what you are really running into.

I use the hex escapes when dealing with quotes so not to have to mess with the C# compiler thinking they are quotes while parsing.

Comment: [Your pattern doesn't match the whole content string.](https://regex101.com/r/kWTDIR/1)

Comment: @Abion47 I agree with you 100%. Because the user is only focused on the text between (an inner) pair of `'`s due to the match capture requirement `(`...`)`, I focused my pattern on that. Unless the OP comes back and says, no I need `match.groups[0]` as well as `match.groups[1]`, I will stick to this answer.

Comment: OP is not only concerned with only the text within the inner apostrophes. It appears he wants the _outer_ apostrophes. In the comments of the code in OP's question, he says that he wanted `Scale['#13212']` as an output. Your pattern chops off the closing square bracket, which tells me that it isn't retrieving the full contents of the string within the outer apostrophes.

Comment: @Abion47 I'm waiting for clarification from the OP before attempting a fix to only to have the OP report other things of need....I have been burned before.

Comment: This isn't a matter of clarification. OP has already stated what they want, and your answer isn't providing it.